# Javascript naming convention for public functions prefixed with dollar sign

Tags: javascript

```
/**
 * @author paula
 */

function A(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.sayHi();
    this.$sayHi();
    this.sayBye();
};

(function(){
    this.sayHi = function(){
        console.log("[sayHi] Hi there, "+ this.name);
    };

    this.$sayHi = function(){
        console.log("[$sayHi] Hi there, " + this.name);
    };

    this.sayBye = function(){
        console.log("[sayBye] Bye bye now, " + this.name);
    };
}).call(A.prototype);

var objA1 = new A("Luca");
```

Found this article:  javascript.crockford.com/code.html where is mentioned that "Do not use $ (dollar sign) or \ (backslash) in names. Most variables and functions should start with a lower case letter"

I have some framework code with many functions prefixed with dollar sign (functions that look similar to $sayHi). Is a function prefixed with $ intended to be used for special purposes ? Thanks.

Comment: The dollar sign is a valid identifier, it makes no difference.

Comment: Dollar sign appears above alphabet characters when function names are sorted alphabetically, and helps separate framework functions from your own functions.

Comment: hey, it's not a duplicate

Comment: Sure looks like a duplicate to me. What distinguishes the two?

Comment: `$` is perhaps the easiest and free non reserved javascript character - this is why jquery use it as their function identifier, basically the shortest thing that was widely available ( annoying to many who used it before jquery became popular : )

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. I'm focused on the function names prefixed with dollar sign and I want to clarify if there is any naming convention regarding that.

Comment: @PaulaCogeanu: There is not really a convention for function (method) names wit dollar signs, even less than for variable (property) names like in the duplicate question. You can use `$` in any identifier just as you want, if some people want to read any deeper meaning into that it's their business and always depends on the context.

Comment: @cookie monster. No. It's not.

Comment: There's no real distinction. `$` is a valid identifier with no magic behavior. Either way, this question has been asked many, many times. The duplicates will give you the answer you're looking for, so I don't know what you're complaining about

Comment: It has to be something that makes the distinction, why to use it ... just because it's pretty and nice to have a function prefixed with dollar sign ?

Comment: People can name functions however they want, and if they want to do something as silly as put a `$` before one, that's up to them. But your question wasn't asking about naming conventions. It was asking about differing behavior, and that also is answered by the duplicates.

Comment: *"...to understand if there is some magic power around the function prefixed with dollar sign ($)"* *"...failed to find if $sayHi is treated differently by JS interpreter"*

Comment: I for one haven't seen any frameworks use a `$` prefix for functions, other than a main function/namespace named `$` in libraries like jQuery and PrototypeJS. So I don't understand why you think it's some sort of convention.

Comment: @cookie monster. I'm focused to understand why and when somebody should choose to prefix his functions with dollar sign. Anyway, it looks more interesting to me the murdoch answer.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea why someone would do that. Using an underscore prefix to denote "no touchy" properties is fairly common. Haven't seen `$` in the wild for that purpose though. I'd have a tough time with an API that actually used `$` for public methods.

Comment: @PaulaCogeanu, I'm seeing the `$` used to prefix jquery selectors quite a bit. `var $myDiv = $("#myDiv");` and also `$this = $(this)` - i like it, can at a glance see that it refers to a jquery object

Comment: @Rob Sedgwick In the provided example it can be seen that $sayHi refers to a function not to a jQuery object ( a div element as you suggested ). I'm looking for a naming convention for functions which are prefixed by $. Thanks anyway for your input.

Comment: @PaulaCogeanu, yeah, I can't see any real reason why folks would prefix with a $, other than when refering to jquery/proto/sizzle objects - must be just a preference of that dev. - saying that if a functon has jquery/proto/sizzle dependancies, it could be could too prefix with $ too. ( i'd like that too )- but, yeah, there are no no rules regarding `$`

Answer (score 0):

You never *have to* prefix anything with a dollar sign, it's just a popular choice in some libraries like jQuery, because `$` is not often used as a normal variable name. The dollar sign is a valid variable name, so it can be used to name any variable.

```
this.$sayHi=function(){/*code*/};
```

and

```
this.sayHi=function(){/*code*/};
```

are just two different variable names with different things assigned to them. You can name a variable anything you want, but putting a dollar sign in front of it doesn't make it special.

Also, of note, is that in jQuery and similar libraries/frameworks, there will always be a dot after the dollar sign. Basically, the frameworks only want to take up one global variable, and they make it the dollar sign, which nobody really should be using as a variable name, since it's kind of really undescriptive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that in JS is perfectly valid to prefix anything(function names) with dollar sign. But what I would like to know is if there is any message to transmit to other developers when you decide to prefix your function with $, message which refers on how the method should be used (to make them aware that the function is public or private).

Answer (score 0):

As per [ECMA 5.1 Standard specification, a variable's identifier is defined](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6) like this

```
Identifier ::
    IdentifierName but not ReservedWord
```

And `IdentifierName` is defined like this

```
IdentifierName ::
    IdentifierStart
    IdentifierName IdentifierPart
```

And `IdentifierStart` is defined, like this

```
IdentifierStart ::
    UnicodeLetter
    $
    _ 
    \ UnicodeEscapeSequence
```

So, `$` is nothing but a character in the variable's name.

Comment: Notice that it's not a variable, but a proberty - where all `IdentifierName`s are allowed

Comment: ok, thank you for your answer. Looks that function names prefixed with more than one dollar sign ($$sayHi or $$$sayHi) are also valid names. The Python convention for making a function/method private is to prefix it with an _ (underscore). $ (dollar sign) in JS has the same meaning as _ (underscore) in Python ?

Comment: @PaulaCogeanu As you said, its just a convention. In JS also, people use `__` for internal or private variables.

Comment: In this article http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html it is stated that: " Do not use $ (dollar sign) or \ (backslash) in names. Do not use _ (underbar) as the first character of a name. It is sometimes used to indicate privacy, but it does not actually provide privacy. If privacy is important, use the forms that provide private members. Avoid conventions that demonstrate a lack of competence.

Most variables and functions should start with a lower case letter."

Comment: I have some code where functions which are prefixed with dollar sign return an array and I do not know if it's a new convention or is sth else.

Comment: @thefourtheye I would like to know what is the convention related to the dollar sign. Found some references saying that a variable prefixed with a $ is a new variable created in global space. I'm looking to clarify this aspect: what is the naming convention for functions prefixed with dollar sign (in my example is $sayHi). Do you have any clue ? Thanks.

Comment: @PaulaCogeanu `__` is quite commonly used, not sure about `$` though. I would not personally use `$` in a variable name though

Answer (score 0):

The dollar sign is like any other letter, as far as javascript is concerned. For instance:

```
var $ = 5;
console.log($);
```

Function names can also have dollar signs:

```
function $() {
   console.log("Hello world!");
}
$();
```

JQuery (and other libraries) create a function dollar sign to do amazing things. It is a good name for these functions because you are not likely to create a method named `$` in your code.